# Item Status Mixed - No Custom options

Tags: magento2, orders

I created an e-shop on Magento ver. 2.0.6. Every product is simple with just a set of custom options for the size. The custom options field is required by the client.

Some orders come in right with their size and their status as: ordered. The problem is that some orders come with a "mixed" item status and no sizes selected.